# Linux (any distro): Find out who signed a file

Tags: ubuntu

I have a file named: shimx64.efi
It was delivered with Knoppix 9.1
How can I know who signed this file ?

I can do the verification on RHEL 8.x, 9.x or Ubuntu 20.04

Thank you,
Zvika

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/126094/how-to-query-efi-signature

Comment: vidarlo - Thank you very much !